# Javascript library source code appears instead of web page

Tags: javascript, html

When I go to a page on our website, it sometimes displays the source code of imported Javascript libraries, instead of the page.

```
/*!
* jQuery UI 1.8.18
*
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI
*/(function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(function(){return
...
```

Refreshing the page seems to make it go away, but I'm wondering why this happens and how to fix it? It doesn't seem to be browser-specific.

Update:
The source looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/js/jquery-ui-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/mainSites.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...//Some other JS
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ...//Some other JS       
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       ...//Yet more
    </script>
    ...other html code
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us how the JS is included ?

Comment: it seems that you have put <script> tags in the body why? also this might cause the problem.

Comment: This looks all fine, and what page do you go to when the problem happens?

Comment: Any page where the JQuery library is imported, but infrequently and randomly.